# Añadir texto en medio de strings php

Tags: php

Tengo una variable en php llamada

```
$nombre = "img.jpg";
```

(El string podra ser: "www.ejemplo.com/content/algo.jpg")

Quiero encontrar la manera de añadir algo en medio del string

```
$nombre = "img-150x150.jpg";
```

La solucion que encontre

```
$imagenTMP = explode(".", $imagen);
$imagen = $imagenTMP[0].'.'.$imagenTMP[1].'.'.$imagenTMP[2]."-150x150.".$imagenTMP[3];
```

Comment: ¿Quieres seguir algún patrón en particular? Poder se puede, pero depende de tus necesidades se puede usar una función u otra.

Comment: quiero cambiar el .jpg y reemplazar por  -150x150.jpg ya que el resto de url puede variar la longitud del string, estuve mirando substr_replace pero nose como empezar por el final

Comment: Como dice @OscarGarcia no es lo mismo si siempre va a ser añadir después de "img" el tamaño, a que unas veces sea "audio" y otras "img".
Recomiendo que además de contestar al comentario, añadas a la pregunta la información que nos des

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos maneras,

**Partiendo el nombre**:

```
$nombre = "img.jpg";
$a = explode(".", $nombre);

$nombre = $a[0]."-150x150.".$a[1];
echo $nombre;
```

Con `explode`, partes `$nombre` en dos por el . (y este queda eliminado, por lo que se tiene que volver a poner)

**Remplazando**:

```
$nombre = "img.jpg";
$nombre =  str_replace(".jpg", "-150x150.jpg", $nombre);
echo $nombre;
```

Este ultimo ejemplo creo que es mejor, ya que no te dará problemas de si en `$nombre` hay algún '.'

Por seguridad, yo cogería la extensión del archivo. YA que así puedes estar tranquilo si te viene un *jpg*, *png*, *gif*, el que sea.

```
$nombre = "img.jpg";
$ext  = explode('.', $nombre);
$ext  = end($ext);
$nombre =  str_replace(".".$ext, "-150x150.".$ext, $nombre);
echo $nombre;
```

Así puedes estar seguro de que te va a cambiar en *string* que le pases la extensión por  el texto que tu quieras

---

Tienes el ejemplo [aqui](http://codepad.org/7TefG7Je)

Comment: Buenas, gracias por responder esto me sirve pero puede que la imagen sea un url asi que habra mas . en el string

Comment: Mirate, el ultimo ejemplo. lo acabo de editar

Comment: Gracias me diste una idea

Comment: Me alegra que te haya ayudado!

Answer (score 1):

¿Quieres que siempre se añada algo justo en la posición central del string?

De ser así, tienes que comprobar la longitud de la cadena y partirla por la mitad, y concatenar lo que quieras justo en medio, esto se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
$nombre = "img.jpg";
$mitad = strlen($nombre ) / 2; //Cantidad de letras en $nombre dividida entre 2 
$parte1 = substr($nombre , 0, $mitad); 
$parte2 = substr($nombre , $mitad); 

//ahora para concatenar, supon que quiero añadir en la mitad la palabra Perro
$total = $parte1 . " Perro " . $parte2 //$total = img Perro .jpg
```

Si lo que quieres es añadir algo antes del `.`, puedes hacerlo con split:

```
$nombre = "img.jpg";
$trozos = explode(".", $nombre); //corta por todos los caracteres . de la cadena y la divide en subcadenas
$anadir = "Perro";
//Ahora solo queda añadir la cadena después del punto, pero si hay mas de un 
//punto hay que pensar en cual añadirlo, según tu ejemplo, entiendo que quieres añadirlo 
//justo antes del último punto (por si el nombre del fichero contiene puntos) 
$elementos = count($trozos); //Con esto sabemos el número de elementos en el array
$final = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $elementos; $i++) {
    $final = $final . $trozos[1];
}
// Ya tenemos todo el string recuperado a falta de la extensión.
$final = $final . $anadir . $trozos[$elementos -1] 
//Con esto último, hemos añadido al final de nuestra cadena, el elemento y su extensión.
```

Espero que te sirva.

Es posible optimizar el código, quizás alguna persona que sepa más de php puede mejorarlo, pero esta solución es válida igualmente.

Ánimo!

Answer (score 1):

Ya que vas a utilizar imagenes, y tu variable $archivo puede ser una url, 
sugiero que utilices las funciones que te provee php al respecto.

Una url podria llegar a tener algo como esto (puede que no sea tu caso, pero podria serlo):

```
$archivo = "www.ejemplo.com/content/content2/algo.jpg?width=10&height=100"
```

lo primero es cojer el path de esta url. Para ello php te provee de **parse_url** (ver http://php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php):

```
$path = parse_url($archivo, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

esto te devuelve "/content/content2/algo.jpg", eliminando lo que hay despues de ? y eliminando el host, protocolo y demas.

Una vez tienes el path, debes obtener el archivo. Para eso, existe ya una funcion en php que te lo soluciona, es **basename** (http://php.net/manual/es/function.basename.php):

```
$archivo = basename($nombre);
```

Esto te devuelve directamente el nombre del archivo, en tu caso "algo.jpg"

Y a partir de aqui, aplicar explode como han comentado en otras soluciones.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un método llamado `explode()` de php que puedes partir el String desde donde quieras y te los almacena en un array.

Un ejemplo de su utilización es esta:

```
$nombre = "img.jpg";
$añadido = "-150x150";

$explode = explode(".", $nombre );  // explode[0] = "img"; / explode[1] = "jpg";

$nombreFinal = explode[0] . $añadido. "." . explode[1]; // "img" + "-150x150" + "." + "jpg".
```

Comment: Gracias igual que al compañero de arriba pero el string original tendra varios puntos

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que se me ocurre, así a bote pronto:

Podrías dividir el String en dos trozos (por un lado el nombre el archivo y por otro lado la extensión del archivo) usando como carácter delimitador el ".".

```
$nombre = "img.jpg";    
$nombre_despiezado = explode(".", $nombre);
```

Luego asignar cada uno de los "trozos" a una variable.

```
$nombre_archivo = $nombre_despiezado[0];
$extension_archivo = $nombre_despiezado[1];
```

Concatenarle lo que quieras al trozo que te interese (en tu caso al final de $nombre_archivo).

```
$nombre_archivo = $nombre_archivo . "-150x150";
```

Y ya solo te quedaría unir de nuevo los pedazos, sin olvidarse de añadirle de nuevo el "." separatorio entre el nombre el archivo y su extensión.

```
$nombre = $nombre_archivo . '.' . $extension_archivo;
```

Espero haberte ayudado ^^